# Rails: how to display all pending friend requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my first Rails project and I have a small problem. I'd really appreciate any help. 
I want to display all pending friend requests for a current user using each iterator. My controller:

```
class FriendRequestsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_friend_request, except: [:index, :new, :create]

def index
  @incoming = FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user)
  @outgoing = current_user.friend_requests
end

def new
  @friend_request = FriendRequest.new
end

def create
  friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
  @friend_request = current_user.friend_requests.new(friend: friend)
  if @friend_request.save
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path), status: :created, location: @friend_request
  else
    render json: @friend_request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

When I try something like a code below, it kinda works, the conditional statement works as it should, but I know it's a terrible way to make it work, so I'd like to use @incoming since it's defined.

```
<% if FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user).present? %>
   <% ?.each do |request| %>
       <li><%= ? %></li>
   <% end %>
<% else %>
    You don't have any friend requests
<% end %>
```

But when I try something like:

```
<% if @incoming.present? %>
```

The conditional statement doesn't work properly and there's 'You don't have any friend requests', even though the current user has a pending friend request.
I don't exactly get how everything works in RoR yet, so I'd be thankful for an explanation.

Comment: Hm, `@incoming.present?` _should_ work. Did you make a typo, perhaps? Also try `@incoming.exists?` (it's a slightly different check)

Comment: Are you sure that the html code you have written lies inside app/views/friend_requests/index.html.erb?

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas thank you. that was the problem, I had tried to do it in a navbar dropdown (what I should've mentioned in my post), after your suggestion I used max's code in  app/views/friend_requests/index.html.erb and it works properly. is there any way to make it work in my navbar?

Comment: Is the nav bar loaded from the same index page? Or where is your code? I meant in which html.erb do you have the navbar?

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas I have the navbar in app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb and I render it in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, so it's visible on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start by creating a specific association for incoming friend requests.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :incoming_friend_requests,
    class_name: 'FriendRequest',
    source: :friend
end
```

Since Rails cannot derive the proper columns from the name of the association we specify the `class_name`. `source` tells Rails what association on FriendRequest is the inverse.

This is extremely important when you start to look at eager loading and performance.

For example it lets you do:

```
@user = User.joins(:friend_requests, :incoming_friend_requests)
            .find(params[:id])
```

So lets use the new relation:

```
def index
  @incoming = current_user.incoming_friend_requests
  @outgoing = current_user.friend_requests
end
```

To test if there are any items in a scope or collection use `.any?`. `.any?` is pretty smart in that it won't issue a query if the association is already loaded.

```
<% if @incoming.any? %>
  <ul>
  <% @incoming.each do |fr| %>
    <li><%= fr.name %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <p>You don't have any friend requests</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `present?` is more useful when checking for the presence of param key, instance variable etc.

Comment: thank you very much for such a long answer, I went full retard and tried to use the code in a navbar dropdown, what I should've mentioned in my question, but I had no idea it's relevant. Your code works perfectly when I put it in app/views/friend_requests/index.html.erb, even without changing anything in my models.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if (frs = FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user)).present? %>
   <% frs.each do |fr| %>
       <li><%= fr.name %></li>
   <% end %>
<% else %>
    You don't have any friend requests
<% end %>
```

Comment: Putting DB queries in a view is bad practice. Getting correct data is not view's concern.

Comment: Answering questions as they are stated is my concern. Dave Thomas has commented frequently about logic in views, and although it can get out of hand, he suggests a pragmatic approach which IMHO is nicer than having umpteen instance variables being set up in your controller (or helpers) for non trivial views... but I digress.. Appreciate the down vote however..

Comment: The point is, the instance var _should have_ worked. There's something else going wrong than we can see here. Your solution is just masking the problem, not solving it.